# Using java web start (jnlp) with several java installed on Windows XP

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

We have Windows XP with Java 1.5 and Java 1.6 installed. We try to launch JNLP file, there specified required Java version 1.5, like here:

http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se

After JNLP file is downloaded, appears Java 1.6 window. Then, appears window that certificate is wrong and application doesn't run. If we uninstall Java 1.6, the application runs properly.

If we remove the above line from the JNLP file, the application runs with Java 1.6 (but it works wrong, since it was developed for Java 1.5)

So, it is important to run the application with Java 1.5.

Please suggest how to run this JNLP file with Java 1.5, while Java 1.6 is also installed in the system.

Here is the jnlp file, i just replaced all organization specific titles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://server_url"> 
  <information>
    <title> Some title </title>  
    <vendor>Some Vendor</vendor>
    <homepage href="some_ulr" /> 
    <description>Product description</description> 
    <icon kind="splash" href="./splash.gif"/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>

  <application-desc main-class="org.eclipse.core.launcher.WebStartMain">
  </application-desc>

    <resources>
    <j2se version="1.5.0_22" />
    <jar href="http://some_jar"/>
    <jar href="http://some_jar1"/>
    <jar href="http://some_jarN"/>
    <property name="server" value="some_server"/>
    <property name="port" value="8080"/>
    </resources>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: The JNLP is invalid.  The `application-desc` element should be last, after the `resources` element.  Maybe some of the other elements are out of the correct order as well - those two are the only ones I can say for sure.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the jnlp file. Tomorrow i will check it with correct environment. I will post an update here.

Comment: The same behavior, no change. Java 1.6 launches the JNLP, then it calls Java 1.5, which starts to run and then exits without any message.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that 1.5 is enabled in the [JNLP Runtime Settings](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html#enable).  Also check that the JNLP is valid, using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) or a DTD/XSD.

[image]

Comment: Checking the jnlp with JaNeLA. It complains with the following: Content type content/unknown does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Comment: @Yuri: Given my crystal ball is broken, would you mind updating your question with the JNLP?  I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using version="1.5+" in your jnlp file.

Comment: Tried, it didn't help. I tried also to specify full Java version, like this: version="1.5.0_22".

Comment: -1  A `version` attribute of `1.5+` means the *latest version* that is at least 1.5.  So if 1.7 was installed, 1.7 would be used.  See my linked page on JWS based JRE version control, for more details.